# Remover todos as subviews de uma Stack View

Tags: swift

Em uma determinada hora da minha aplicação eu consumo um API e adiciono botões em uma Stack View.

O nome da minha Stack view é "viewPossibleAnswer".

```
for answer in newListsResponses {
 let newButton = UIButton()
 newButton.setTitle(answer.sentence, for: .normal)
 newButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
 self.viewPossibleAnswer.addSubview(newButton)
}
```

Dessa maneira está inserindo muito bem os botões mas eu preciso remover todos os botões de dentro da Stack View em determinada hora.

Fiz a seguinte função para tentar remover todos os botões de dentro da Stack View.

```
for itemSubView in self.viewPossibleAnswer.arrangedSubviews{
 self.viewPossibleAnswer.removeArrangedSubview(itemSubView)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ricardo, você também pode utilizar a sintaxe *shorthand* a seguir para realizar o mesmo:

```swift
viewPossibleAnswer.subviews.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperview() })
```

No exemplo, sugeri o uso do método `forEach`, que aceita um parâmetro: a *closure* a ser executada para cada elemento da sequência/coleção.

O *shorthand* mencionado nada mais é do que um atalho da linguagem, para que o código fique mais conciso, se assim for desejado. Basicamente, é equivalente ao seguinte:

```swift
viewPossibleAnswer.subviews.forEach({ itemSubView in

  itemSubView.removeFromSuperview()

})
```

Fica a seu critério utilizar ou não a sintaxe *shorthand*, normalmente é boa para casos simples/curtos assim, pois deixa o código mais legível (sem quebras/indentações).

Se quiser entender melhor, segue a referência (seção *Shorthand Argument Names*): https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html.

Answer (score 0):

Eu estava errado já que eu estou adicionando "subviews" a função correta é acessar os valor das "subviews" de minha Stack View então mudei minha função.

```
for itemSubView in self.viewPossibleAnswer.subviews{
 itemSubView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Espero que isso possa ajudar.